# How to load balance publish/subscribe websocket requests to node server using nginx as a load balancer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, socket.io, rabbitmq

I have following scenario. I want to implement pub/sub model using socket.io library on node.js with rabbitmq as queueing service. A particular websocket can act as a publisher or subscriber depending upon query string like following requst

```
var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:8000?type=publisher&id=1");
```

Similarly for Subscriber

```
var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:8000?type=subscriber&id=1");
```

Now i have maintained a rabbitmq at backend to provide this funcitonality, with node.js server. Any publisher publishers into central Exchange of rabbitmq with different topics being formed for each subscriber depending upon "id" (specified in url) for which it will listen. Everything works fine with no load balancer in front of node.js servers. 
          But PROBLEM arises when i want to use nginx as a load balancer in front of node servers. Now the architecture i m following is that each node sever has its own rabbitmq server to keep track of publishers and subscribers.  So in order to implement pub/sub model it should be made mandatory that a subscriber request for a particular id should go to same server where request for publisher of that particular id went. But how to keep track of which node server nginx sent publisher requst, so that the request for subscriber of same id can be directed to same server for pub/sub model to be implemented.

TL;DR:- Is there a  way to keep track or requests sent to which node server specified in "upstream " cluster of nginx. ??? Is there extra module in nginx? If no , then how to resolve the problem i m facing?

Thanks